# AWS CLI S3 CP --recursive function works in console but not in .sh file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have the following line inside of a `.sh` file:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/folder/ /home/ec2-user/ --recursive
```

When I run this line in the console, it runs fine and completes as expected. When I run this line inside of a `.sh` file, the line returns the following error.

```
Unknown options: --recursive
```

Here is my full `.sh` script.

```
echo "Test"
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/folder/ /home/ec2-user/ --recursive
echo "Test"
python /home/ec2-user/Run.py
```

If I manually add the Run.py file (not having it copied over from S3 as desired) and run the script I get the following output.

```
Test

Unknown options: --recursive
Test
Hello World
```

If I remove the files which are expected to be transferred by S3 out of the Linux environment and rely on the AWS S3 command I get the following output:

```
Test

Unknown options: --recursive
Test
python: can't open file '/home/ec2-user/Run.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Note that there are multiple files that can be transferred inside of the specified S3 location. All of these files are transferred as expected when running the AWS command from the console.

I initially thought this was a line ending error, as I am copying the `.sh` file over from Windows. I have made sure that my line endings are working and we see this by the rest of the script running as expected. As a result, this issue seems isolated to the actual AWS command. If I remove the `--recursive` from the call, it will transfer over a single file successfully.

Any ideas on why the --recursive option would be working in the console but not in the `.sh` file?

P.s.

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.15 Python/3.7.3 Linux/4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64 exe/x86_64.amzn.2 prompt/off
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is about the position of the option or you have somewhere the AWS CLI path which is pointing to older version because **recursive option was added later**. For me, it works both ways inside the shell script as well as the console.

```
aws s3 cp --recursive  s3://bucket/folder/ /home/ec2-user/ 

$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.6 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/20.2.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

Try printing the version inside the shell script.

**cp --recursive** method lists source path and copies (overwrites) all to the destination path.

Plus instead of doing recursive use [sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).sync recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

```
aws s3 sync 3://bucket/folder/ /home/ec2-user/
```

**sync** method first lists both source and destination paths and copies only differences (name, size etc.).

Comment: so this technology works in that it removes the error and both methods work inside the console. However, when either method is applied inside the `.sh` file, the transfer of files still never occurs. It just isn't erroring out any longer. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the permission differences ? Not IAM rolebut .sh

Comment: That's a good question. I am not entirely sure how to answer as I am pretty new to linux. What I can say is that am using the default AWS Linux login method and calling the `.sh` script via `./aws_script.sh`.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I can confirm this is not a permissions issue at least from the error message I can deduce that. Plus both ways I am assuming the credentials are being picked from ENV vars because I don't see he is using the profile or hard coding the credentials somewhere.

Comment: @JeremyThompson (base) [ec2-user@ip-111-111-111-11 ~]$ ./aws_script.sh           -      

Note: I am just trying to get an AWS Data Pipeline to work from this `.sh`. If there is a better way to be running the `.sh` I am totally open to it.

Comment: @WolVes may be you can change the --recursive option to sync and try.

Comment: I have tried that. Again no error, but also no file transfer. Works perfectly in the console though!

Comment: sync will not do any transfer as I described above if there are no changes in the source.  Try priting the aws cli version inside the shell script and see if that's the same you have shared here.

Comment: @samtoddler, so for testing I have removed all of the files that are in the S3 bucket from the Linux system. Therefore Sync should pull them over as I have seen it do inside the console command. It is not doing that when inside the `.sh` file. When I add `echo $(aws --version)` inside the `.sh` I get the same output as above. `aws-cli/2.1.15 Python/3.7.3 Linux/4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64 exe/x86_64.amzn.2 prompt/off`

Comment: aws s3 cp -- recursive --dryrun s33://bucket/folder/ /home/ec2-user/and aws s3 sync --recursive --dryrun s3://bucket/folder/ /home/ec2-user/ and see if it prints anything .

Comment: Unfortunately no change in behavior. No errors, but no file transfers. The cp version spits stuff out to the screen (similar to how it does with console command). Sync does not spit out anything (regardless of --dryrun or not), which is different than when run in  console. I have tried running both with sudo in front of the `.sh` file to no avail. I am leaning back towards a permissions issue again at this point.

Comment: `(base) [ec2-user@ip-172-11-11-111 ~]$ ls -l ./aws_script.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 103 Dec 31 17:33 ./aws_script.sh
`

Comment: the above behaviour confirms that both commands are working fine syntactically if you had permissions issue it would have been very clear in the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226676/discussion-between-samtoddler-and-wolves).

Comment: @samtoddler, you saved me ton of time. sync works much better than cp. Thank you!